# Cant use InitAppointmentImages event with extended Class

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, scheduler

i have an XtraScheduler and want to show some picture on my Appointments. The DevExpress knowledge Base show me this article: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraSchedulerSchedulerControl_InitAppointmentImagestopic

They describe the InitAppointmentImages event and it looks like exactly what iam searching for, but i have one problem.

The EventArgs of the InitAppointmentImages event give me the actual Appoinment. In my Project i have a class which is extended from Appointment. This class is used as DataSource for the XtraScheduler (List). So i thought that i can do following:

```
private void myCalendar_InitAppointmentImages(object sender, AppointmentImagesEventArgs e)
{
    MyClass obj = e.Appointment as MyClass;

    if (obj != null)
    {
        AppointmentImageInfo info = new AppointmentImageInfo();
        info.Image = MyImageCollection.Images[0];
        e.ImageInfoList.Add(info);
    }
}
```

But obj is always null! :( I cant understand that because MyClass is extended from Appointment and the DataSource is from Type MyClass. That this hierarchie is working fine shows this example which is working:

```
    MyClass obj = (MyClass)MyCalendar.SelectedAppointments[0].GetSourceObject(MyStorage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using this to get your `MyClass` object:

```
MyClass obj = (MyClass)MyCalendar.SelectedAppointments[0].GetSourceObject(MyStorage);
```

than you need to do the same with `e.Appointment`:

```
MyClass obj = e.Appointment.GetSourceObject(MyStorage) as MyClass;
```

Comment: Yes this is absolutly sensefull. Thanks :)